# Is there more than one harmonic number that is natural?

Tags: harmonic-numbers

n-th harmonic number is:

$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$

is there some $n\neq1$ for which $H_n$ is a natural number?

Or can it be proven that there is no such number?

Comment: There is no such number. You can show it by checking that the denominator of $H_n$ is even but the numerator of $H_n$ is odd, for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no examples other than $n=1$. This can be seen as a result of [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate). Moreover, for all $n \geq 2$ the numerator of $H_{n}$ is an odd number while the denominator of $H_{n}$ is an even number.

[Here](http://mathheaven.blogspot.com/2008/05/nth-harmonic-number-cannot-be-integer.html) is a fairly elementary proof.

Comment: Thanks for answer and the link. Although it will take me some time to understand the proof. (I'm just a hobbyist).